# Docker 24.0.5 on Ubuntu 22.04 (using Ubuntu repositories, not Docker Official PPA repo)

Tags: docker

I've installed docker today (10th of October) using below command:

```
sudo apt install docker-buildx 
(latest version 0.11.2-0ubuntu1~22.04.1)
```

It installed among others docker.io package. I see that docker --version returns

```
Docker version 24.0.5, build 24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
```

I know there was below bug that blocked the new 24.0.5 on Ubuntu 22.04 but as per launchapd it was fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker-buildx/+bug/1968035

Now I'm trying to run my scripts that perfectly work on docker from Official Docker PPA, but fail in apt version of docker 24.0.5 in Ubuntu:

```
docker  compose  --parallel 1  -f "my_file" down

unknown flag: --parallel
See 'docker --help'.
```

I'm checking official documentation for docker and I see that the flag is mentioned there so it shouldn't be complaining:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/

What am I missing? I just want to use docker with one click installation from Ubuntu without PPA shenanigans. Also I need docker 24+ so downgrading to older 20.x.x version doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Are you sure you have installed the docker compose plugin?**

It's separate installation package in ubuntu apt repositories:

```
sudo apt install docker-compose-v2
```

Version V2 is the proper one as the V1 was officially deprecated.
See the deprecation banner at https://docs.docker.com/compose/

I'm aware of 2 main plugins for docker: buildx + compose.

You can check if those are installed by executing simply 'docker' in command line and looking in the output (here truncated for readability):

```
Management Commands:
...
  buildx*     Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., 0.11.2)
...
  compose*    Docker Compose (Docker Inc., 2.20.2+ds1-0ubuntu1~22.04.1)
...
```

Comment: Great! You are right! This compose plugin is not installed by default, now the compose sub-command and parallel flags work like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I also struggled with this. A bit different installation that using the PPA, but at least no need for keyring and custom PPA ;)